# UIButton as subview programmatically constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, constraints

I have one UIScrollView (IBOutlet) with success constraint inside a storyboard. then I programmatically create UIButton and put them as a subview to UIScrollView. how do I programmatically set these UIButton constraints so their height and size would tally with their super view?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var aScrollView: UIScrollView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var xCoord: CGFloat = 5
    let yCoord: CGFloat = 5
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 100
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 100

    let gapBetweenButtons: CGFloat = 10


    var itemCount = 0

    // MARK: - filter buttons
    for i in 0..<6 {

        itemCount = i

        let aButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        aButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
        aButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        aButton.layer.cornerRadius = aButton.frame.size.width / 2
        aButton.clipsToBounds = true

        xCoord += buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons

        aScrollView.addSubview(aButton)   
    }
}
```

Comment: @mclovin  Firstly viewDidLoad is not for putting down all that code.Keep your code clean.:)

Comment: @matt yes no constraints in them. as you can see i hardcoded the size of uibutton for now. hence the question. i need those uibutton to resize accordingly to aScrollView. i successfully set aScrollView constraint via storyboard and now asking help to set constraint for aButton via code. Sorry to confuse.

Comment: To further add to @matt comment... "i need those unbutton to **resize accordingly** to aScrollView"... what does *that* mean? Sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words...

Comment: @dfd i need to make those button would fit according to superview. hope you could help. these are the images of now. as you can see those buttons' size are same for all device. http://imgur.com/a/SvlHk http://imgur.com/a/G6BV3

Answer (score 1):

Try this --

This is just an idea about how to add constraint programmatically.

For more understanding you can go through below link - https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nslayoutanchor

```
 let myButton = UIButton()
 self.aScrollView.addSubview(myButton)

 self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
 myButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: forView. aScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
 myButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: forView. aScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
 myButton.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100.0).active = true
 myButton.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100.0).active = true
```

Comment: forView - on which you want to add button mean superview for button.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var xCoord: CGFloat = 5
        let yCoord: CGFloat = 5

        let gapBetweenButtons: CGFloat = 10


        let buttonCount = 6
        let buttonWidth = (aScrollView.frame.width - CGFloat(buttonCount - 1) * gapBetweenButtons - xCoord - xCoord) / CGFloat(buttonCount) // - (2 * xCoord) = - (margin left + margin right).
        let buttonHeight = buttonWidth

        var itemCount = 0

        // MARK: - filter buttons
        for i in 0..<buttonCount {

            itemCount = i

            let aButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            aButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
            aButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            aButton.layer.cornerRadius = aButton.frame.size.width / 2
            aButton.clipsToBounds = true

            xCoord += buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons

            aScrollView.addSubview(aButton)
        }
    }
```

Comment: not succes.
iphone se - http://imgur.com/a/G6BV3
iphone 7 - http://imgur.com/a/SvlHk
but thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I have mistaken. Checkout my answer again.

Comment: @mclovin I have tested in simulator: iphone 5: http://imgur.com/a/hdrPW iphone 7: http://imgur.com/a/8Ptcu

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it. I made a video tutorial for you [add unbutton programmatically to scrollview in iOS, swift](https://youtu.be/fVrCZ2S9WSQ). please refer the link.

1. add a scrollview (add constraints -> top, bottom, left, right).
2. then add a view to your scroll view (add constraints -> top, bottom, left, right, width, height and set width and height as you need. explain in the video)
3. add those two views as subviews.
4. then add the button and its constraints programmatically.

**follow the video tutorial. [add UIButton(outlet) to scrollview programmatically](https://youtu.be/fVrCZ2S9WSQ)**